# What is so special about octahedral stresses?

Tags: material-science, continuum-mechanics, stress-strain, solid-mechanics

Octahedral stresses are described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_stress_tensor#Octahedral_stresses). Octahedral shear stress failure criterion is also called as distortion energy failure criterion. Moreover, famous von Mises yield criterion is related with Octahedral shear stress failure criterion as given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Mises_yield_criterion#Physical_interpretation_of_the_von_Mises_yield_criterion). Probably, one of the very first things introduced in continuum plasticity is von Mises criterion, and it is based on Octahedral shear stress.

My question is what is so special with Octahedral stresses? Just they are invariant? Why other criteria, such as maximum principal stress etc., are not used to define yield criteria?

Comment: It would be useful if you could make your question self contained by adding what you understand of the problem.  It would also make it easier to immediately understand the conceptual problems you are facing.

Comment: I think I made that clear  _Why other criteria, such as maximum principal stress etc., are not used to define yield criteria?_

Comment: Choosing the "best" yield criterion for a particular material depends on *experiment*, not mathematical theory. For example, maximum principal stress is a useful *failure* criterion for brittle materials, (but it is not a *yield* criterion, because brittle materials don't yield!) but it doesn't work well for ductile materials. See http://www.learnengineering.org/2012/12/theories-of-failure.html  or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_failure_theory